# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException Line 44 (Selenium Cucumber Training Day 3)

Tags: java, selenium

I'm currently working on Selenium Cucumber Training Day 3, and I'm trying to work through the TestNG Lab exercise as shown in the attached PowerPoint. I'm not sure what is causing the issue, and the weird thing is, most of the code had worked before. Below is the main code and below that is the code for the xml file.

```
package TestNGOnePack;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class TestNG {
    File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Users\\ShaneFitzsimmons\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    private static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void OpenPage() {
        driver.get("http://www.automationpractice.com/");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @BeforeTest
    public void StartBrowser() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ShaneFitzsimmons\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("marionette", true);
    caps.setCapability("browser","firefox");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(caps);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        **driver.get("http://www.automationpractice.com/");**
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div[2]/div/div/nav/div[1]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("ab@abc.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='passwd']")).sendKeys("abc1234");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='SubmitLogin']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block_top_menu']/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='layered_category_8']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='layered_quantity_1']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='layered_condition_new']")).click();
        new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("selectProductSort"))).selectByVisibleText("Price: Lowest first");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='center_column']/ul/li[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a"))).click();
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='category']/div[2]/div/div/a"))).click();
        WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div[2]/div/div/nav/div[2]/a"))).click();
}
    @AfterTest
    public void CloseBrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }
    }

!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" 

suite name = "Test Suite NG" parallel="tests"
 test name = "EmailTest"
  parameter name = "email" value = "ab@abc.com" /
  classes
   class name = "TestNGOnePack.TestNG" /
  /classes
 /test
 test name = "PasswordTest"
  parameter name = "passwd" value = "abc1234" /
  classes
   class name = "TestNGOnePack.TestNG" /
  /classes
 /test 
/suite
```

Comment: Opps, ignore the PowerPoint attachment message as I didn't see a place to upload the PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using main() method with your test.

main() method is needed to run Java programs but when we write tests in TestNg we don't use main() method as we are using testNG annotations.So you don't need to write main() method, TestNg do that by itself.

Change your code as :

```
public class TestNG {
    public static WebDriver driver;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @BeforeTest
    public void StartBrowser() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ShaneFitzsimmons\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("marionette", true);
    caps.setCapability("browser","firefox");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(caps);
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        driver.get("http://www.automationpractice.com/");  
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div[2]/div/div/nav/div[1]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("ab@abc.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='passwd']")).sendKeys("abc1234");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='SubmitLogin']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block_top_menu']/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='layered_category_8']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='layered_quantity_1']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='layered_condition_new']")).click();
        new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("selectProductSort"))).selectByVisibleText("Price: Lowest first");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='center_column']/ul/li[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a"))).click();
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='category']/div[2]/div/div/a"))).click();
        WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div[2]/div/div/nav/div[2]/a"))).click();
}
    @AfterTest
    public void CloseBrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but now I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException error on the driver.get line.

Comment: If your previous exception get resolved then accept the answer and post new question with updated code and error log.